# 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using consobyte PHP SDK for QuickBooks Desktop and when I try to add Non Inventory Item, it throws the error-0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ItemNonInventoryAddRq requestID="38">
      <ItemNonInventoryAdd>
        <Name>46428</Name>
        <SalesAndPurchase>
          <SalesDesc>Apple Watch (not Sport)</SalesDesc>
          <SalesPrice>50.00</SalesPrice>
          <IncomeAccountRef>
            <FullName>Merchandise Sales</FullName>
          </IncomeAccountRef>
          <PurchaseDesc>Apple Watch (not Sport)</PurchaseDesc>
          <PurchaseDesc>50.00</PurchaseDesc>
          <ExpenseAccountRef>
            <FullName>Repairs and Maintenance</FullName>
          </ExpenseAccountRef>
        </SalesAndPurchase>
      </ItemNonInventoryAdd>
    </ItemNonInventoryAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix this:

```
   <PurchaseDesc>Apple Watch (not Sport)</PurchaseDesc>
   <PurchaseDesc>50.00</PurchaseDesc>
```

Anytime you get this error message:

> 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

The first thing you should do is look at your XML closely. And then run it through the `XML Validator` tool included with the QuickBooks SDK. It tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
Line: 15
LinePos: 25
Src Text: <PurchaseDesc>50.00</PurchaseDesc>
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: PurchaseCost, PurchaseTaxCodeRef, ExpenseAccountRef, PrefVendorRef.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome.