# Not able to add data in Other1 and Other2 columns of Invoice in Quickbooks desktop

Tags: asp.net, xml, quickbooks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <InvoiceAddRq requestID="2">
         <InvoiceAdd>
            <CustomerRef>
               <ListID>80000002-1572341266</ListID>
            </CustomerRef>
            <TxnDate>2019-10-26</TxnDate>
            <RefNumber />
            <PONumber>65</PONumber>
            <SalesRepRef>
               <ListID>80000001-1572347694</ListID>
            </SalesRepRef>
            <FOB>gdgdgs</FOB>
            <InvoiceLineAdd>
               <ItemRef>
                  <ListID>8000000E-1572333361</ListID>
               </ItemRef>
               <Amount>0.00</Amount>
               <Other1>India</Other1>
               <Other2>Punjab</Other2>
            </InvoiceLineAdd>
         </InvoiceAdd>
      </InvoiceAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Above is the xml for creating invoice but when I am adding other1 and other2 columns in Invoice It is giving XML parse stream error.

Comment: Kindly help me!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253572/0x80040400-quickbooks-found-an-error-when-parsing-the-provided-xml-text-stream)

Comment: I think it will work.I will Try first and then answer whether its working or not.

Comment: Now I am getting error ...."Src Text: <Other1>ac</Other1>
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema."

Comment: Actually the issue was the version of my qbxml. I have now updated my version to 13.0 in place of 2.0 and the issue got resolved.Answering here because if someday will face the same issue can get help.